# C# Telegram.bot пара вопросов о нем

Tags: c#

Telegram bot examples по ссылке https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples — [image: шаблон telegram.bot examples] — каждый из этих 4 проектов - это 4 разных бота или это элементы одного целого?

И насчет webhook, в описании сказано: "### Set Webhook
From ngrok you get an URL to your local server. It’s important to use the `https` one. You can post this url als form-data (key: url, value: https://yoursubdomain.ngrok.io/api/update) to the telegram api.
https://api.telegram.org/botYourBotToken/setWebhook
Be aware of the **bot** prefix in front of your bot token in the URL."

Куда необходимо прописывать данные настройки? 
И для чего нужны контроллеры? 
Thanks a lot)

Comment: `каждый из этих 4 проектов - это 4 разных бота или это элементы одного целого?` есть какие то свои соображения на этот счет? Поглядите на названия проектов, их типы, может возникнет какая мысль от этого.

Comment: @tym32167, мысль должна возникнуть раньше, если подумать, какой из файлов надо открывать в VS. UPDATE: Хотя стоп. Кажется, эта мысль наоборот запутывает. А нафига так делать??